# Get unique objects From List of Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have class object like this:

```
    public class SD
    {
        public string s { get; set; }
    }

    public class Obj
    {
        public string p { get; set; }
        public string u { get; set; }
        public List<SD> sD { get; set; }
    }

    public class ObjAssignStudy
    {
        public List<Obj> obj { get; set; }
    }
```

And I get that data in this way:

```
{
  "obj":[
    {"p":"1","usertype":"A","studyData":[{"study":"1"},{"study":"2"}]},
    {"p":"2","usertype":"A","studyData":[{"study":"1"}]}
    {"p":"1","usertype":"A","studyData":[{"study":"2"},{"study":"3"}]}
  ]
}
```

What i want is, I want to get distinct P and append coresponding s to it ie. I want final object to contain data like this:

```
{
  "obj":[
    {"p":"1","usertype":"A","studyData":[{"study":"1"},{"study":"2"},{"study":"3"}]},
    {"p":"2","usertype":"A","studyData":[{"study":"1"}]}
  ]
}
```

Any way by which I can achieve this in c# or linq?

Comment: Use Json library and deserialize this Json that you are receiving and make sure the key names match in both, Json and your class properties. That should do it.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But could you please elaborate on how to go about it.

Comment: We're not providing tutorials here, but you can search for Json.NET for example and follow tutorials.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You can use Json.Net or Newtonsoft.Json for this purpose. Documentations are easily available. Put in some efforts yourself unless you dont aim to make better of yourself.

Comment: Yes you can distinct your object then serialize to JSON, imho it is cleaner to manipulate at JSON

Comment: always use nice names instead of s, p, u, sP even if it is a sample.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks for the valuable suggestion

Comment: @Developer Are you serious with those names? Are you trying to obfuscate your code?

Comment: Yes I have named the object as per the naming conventions in my code, it just for the sample object I have renamed it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var objs = new List<Obj>(){
    new Obj 
    { 
        p = "1",
        u = "A",
        sD = new List<SD>() {new SD() { s = "1"}, new SD() { s = "2"}}
    },
    new Obj 
    { 
        p = "2",
        u = "A",
        sD = new List<SD>() {new SD() { s = "1"}}
    },
    new Obj 
    { 
        p = "1",
        u = "A",
        sD = new List<SD>() {new SD() { s = "2"}, new SD() { s = "3"}}
    }
};

var distinct = from obj in objs
               group obj by new { obj.p } into g
               select new Obj {
                   p = g.Key.p,
                   u = g.First().u, 
                   sD = g.SelectMany(i => i.sD).Distinct().ToList() 
               };
```

Modify class `SD` to use `Distinct`

```
public class SD
{
    public string s { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return string.Equals(s, (obj as SD).s);
    } 

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return s.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I use Distinct to get the values?

Comment: @Developer The `Distinct()` is just inside the linq, after `SelectMany()`. To get the `Distinct()` work, you should modify the `SD` adding 2 override functions like the sample

Comment: it helped a lot. Now I want to change it slightly. As per your code, you are grouping obj by obj.p and obj.u. I would like to group only by obj.p. ie. if if u is different then take the first one. How can I do that?

Comment: ie: if `{
  "obj":[
    {"p":"1","usertype":"A","studyData":[{"study":"1"},{"study":"2"}]},
    {"p":"2","usertype":"A","studyData":[{"study":"1"}]}
    {"p":"1","usertype":"B","studyData":[{"study":"2"},{"study":"3"}]}
  ]
}`
then final result should be:
`{
  "obj":[
    {"p":"1","usertype":"A","studyData":[{"study":"1"},{"study":"2"},{"study":"3"}]},
    {"p":"2","usertype":"A","studyData":[{"study":"1"}]}
  ]
}`

Comment: @Developer Yes, just change `u = g.First.u,`

Answer (score 0):

In this particular scenario you can use [indexer](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_indexers.htm) to take particular `List<SD>` corresponding to the value you are passing to the `object` please go through the code that will explain it in detail;

Creation of `Indexer`

```
public List<SD> this[string index]
{
   get
     {
       foreach (Obj item in ListObj)
        {
          if (item.p == index)
          return item.sD;
        }
        return new List<SD>();
     }              
 }
```

In the main function you can access the indexer and store Collect the details as the follows:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ObjAssignStudy newInstance = new ObjAssignStudy();
        List<SD> sampleData=newInstance["b"];// Gives the output
       //collection as : EmptyList1,EmptyList2
    }
```

Complete Code for your reference is here:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ObjAssignStudy newInstance = new ObjAssignStudy();
         List<SD> sampleData=newInstance["c"];
        }
        public class SD
        {
            public string s { get; set; }
        }

        public class Obj
        {
            public string p { get; set; }
            public string u { get; set; }
            public List<SD> sD { get; set; }
        }

        public class ObjAssignStudy
        {

            private List<Obj> _ListObj= new List<Obj>();
            internal List<Obj> ListObj
            {
                get { return _ListObj; }
                set { _ListObj = value; }
            }
            List<SD> tempList = new List<SD>(); 
            public ObjAssignStudy()
            {
                tempList.Add(new SD() { s = "EmptyList1" });
                ListObj.Add(new Obj() { p = "a", sD = tempList, u = "B" });
                tempList.Add(new SD() { s = "EmptyList2" });
                ListObj.Add(new Obj() { p = "b", sD =tempList, u = "C" });
                tempList.Add(new SD() { s = "EmptyList3" });
                ListObj.Add(new Obj() { p = "c", sD =tempList, u = "D" });               
            }
            public List<SD> this[string index]
            {
                get
                {
                    foreach (Obj item in ListObj)
                    {
                        if (item.p == index)
                            return item.sD;
                    }
                    return new List<SD>();
                }              
            }
        }
    }
```

Test Cases:
     List sampleData=newInstance["a"];// Gives the output

> EmptyList1

```
 List<SD> sampleData=newInstance["a"];// Gives the output
```

> EmptyList1
>   EmptyList2

```
 List<SD> sampleData=newInstance["a"];// Gives the output
```

> EmptyList1
>   EmptyList2
>   EmptyList3